# Unable to fix "Ambiguous type variable" in Aeson and Spock

Tags: json, haskell, aeson, haskell-wai, haskell-spock

I have a Spock application where I have this:

```
    post "/test" $ do
        a <- jsonBody'
        text "test"
```

It throws an exception:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘jsonBody'’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Aeson.FromJSON a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Aeson.FromJSON Aeson.DotNetTime
```

thus I've tried solving it like this:

```
post "/test" $ do
        a <- jsonBody' :: Aeson.Object
        text "test"
```

but have had no luck:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘ActionCtxT
                             () (WebStateM () MySession MyAppState) ()’
                     with ‘unordered-containers-0.2.8.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                             T.Text b0’
      Expected type: hvect-0.4.0.0:Data.HVect.HVectElim
                       '[] (SpockActionCtx () () MySession MyAppState ())
        Actual type: unordered-containers-0.2.8.0:Data.HashMap.Base.HashMap
                       T.Text b0
```

How to fix it?

update:

this doesn't fix the problem:

```
        a <- jsonBody' :: Aeson.Object
        --a :: Aeson.Object <- jsonBody'
        let b = show a -- using a
        text "fdsfd"
```

Answer (score 3):

`a <- jsonBody' :: Aeson.Object` gives `Aeson.Object` as the signature to `jsonBody'`. But that doesn't work: `jsonBody'` is not a value but an *action* from which such a value is obtained! You probably want to give that signature to `a`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeSignatures #-}

post "/test" $ do
    a :: Aeson.Object <- jsonBody'
    text "test"
```

Really, you probably don't need anything like that though – just make sure you actually *use* `a`, then the compiler will probably be able to figure out its type on its own!

Comment: I don't want to use the extension, how to archive that without it?

Comment: using "a" doesn't help.

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables` is totally harmless, universally supported, and a useful thing for everyday Haskell programming regardless. Here I don't even make use of that extension anyway, just use it to lift a somewhat arbitrary syntactic restriction. — But as I said: if you _use_ `a` (actually use it as a value, not just feed it to `show` – i.e., it must occur in a _monomorphic position_) then you don't need any explicit signature, either. Alternatively, you can use it in a polymorphic spot like `show` but give a signature there: `show (a :: Aeson.Object)`. That doesn't need `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: I don't want to use the extension, how to archive that without it?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, ok. How can I extract a value from it? I've tried `.:` like this `myVal <- (a :: Object) .: "some_key" ` but it caused typed mismatch because it required the type `‘ActionCtxT ctx0 m0’` to return on each line inside the `do`